# how to convert delphi code from c++ code

Tags: delphi

I know i will get down vote for this. but still i am posting this question

will any one please convert following two function code in delphi.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "multimon.h"    

#define MONITOR_CENTER     0x0001        // center rect to monitor 
#define MONITOR_CLIP     0x0000        // clip rect to monitor 
#define MONITOR_WORKAREA 0x0002        // use monitor work area 
#define MONITOR_AREA     0x0000        // use monitor entire area 

// 
//  ClipOrCenterRectToMonitor 
// 
//  The most common problem apps have when running on a 
//  multimonitor system is that they "clip" or "pin" windows 
//  based on the SM_CXSCREEN and SM_CYSCREEN system metrics. 
//  Because of app compatibility reasons these system metrics 
//  return the size of the primary monitor. 
// 
//  This shows how you use the multi-monitor functions 
//  to do the same thing.    

    void ClipOrCenterRectToMonitor(LPRECT prc, UINT flags)
    {
        HMONITOR hMonitor;
        MONITORINFO mi;
        RECT        rc;
        int         w = prc->right  - prc->left;
        int         h = prc->bottom - prc->top;

        // 
        // get the nearest monitor to the passed rect. 
        // 
        hMonitor = MonitorFromRect(prc, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

        // 
        // get the work area or entire monitor rect. 
        // 
        mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);
        GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &mi);

        if (flags & MONITOR_WORKAREA)
            rc = mi.rcWork;
        else
            rc = mi.rcMonitor;

        // 
        // center or clip the passed rect to the monitor rect 
        // 
        if (flags & MONITOR_CENTER)
        {
            prc->left   = rc.left + (rc.right  - rc.left - w) / 2;
            prc->top    = rc.top  + (rc.bottom - rc.top  - h) / 2;
            prc->right  = prc->left + w;
            prc->bottom = prc->top  + h;
        }
        else
        {
            prc->left   = max(rc.left, min(rc.right-w,  prc->left));
            prc->top    = max(rc.top,  min(rc.bottom-h, prc->top));
            prc->right  = prc->left + w;
            prc->bottom = prc->top  + h;
        }
    }

    void ClipOrCenterWindowToMonitor(HWND hwnd, UINT flags)
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);
        ClipOrCenterRectToMonitor(&rc, flags);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, rc.left, rc.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    }
```

flowing i tried:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure ClipOrCenterRectToMonitor(prc:Integer ; flags:UINT );
   type
  HMONITOR = type THandle;
 var

   // hMonitor : HMONITOR ;
    mi : MONITORINFO ;
    rc : RECT        ;
    w : Integer;
    h :  Integer;

 begin
     w := prc->right  - prc->left;
     h := prc->bottom - prc->top;


    //
    // get the nearest monitor to the passed rect.
    //
    hMonitor := MonitorFromRect(prc, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

    //
    // get the work area or entire monitor rect.
    //
    mi.cbSize := sizeof(mi);
    GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &mi);

    if (flags & MONITOR_WORKAREA) then
        rc := mi.rcWork;
    else
        rc := mi.rcMonitor;

    //
    // center or clip the passed rect to the monitor rect
    //
    if (flags & MONITOR_CENTER) then
    begin
        prc->left   := rc.left + (rc.right  - rc.left - w) / 2;
        prc->top    := rc.top  + (rc.bottom - rc.top  - h) / 2;
        prc->right  := prc->left + w;
        prc->bottom := prc->top  + h;
    end;
    else
    begin
        prc->left   := max(rc.left, min(rc.right-w,  prc->left));
        prc->top    := max(rc.top,  min(rc.bottom-h, prc->top));
        prc->right  := prc->left + w;
        prc->bottom := prc->top  + h;
    end;
  end;

procedure ClipOrCenterWindowToMonitor(hwand:HWND; flags:UINT);
var
  rd:RECT ;
 begin

    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);
    ClipOrCenterRectToMonitor(&rc, flags);
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, rc.left, rc.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
   end;




end.
```

but this is not complete one. please any one do this.

Comment: This is not how SO works. This is not a code translation service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a direct translation of the C code from the MSDN article [Positioning Objects on a Multiple Display Setup (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162826(v=vs.85).aspx) you used as a base. It compiles without errors or warnings on both D2007 and Delphi Berlin, although I haven't tested it to see if the MSDN code actually works.

```
uses
  Windows, MultiMon, Math;

procedure ClipOrCenterRectToMonitor(var Prc: TRect; var Flags: UINT);
var
  hMon: HMONITOR;
  mi: MONITORINFO;
  Rect: TRect;
  w, h: Integer;
const
  MONITOR_CENTER  =   $0001;        // center rect to monitor
  MONITOR_CLIP  =   $0000;        // clip rect to monitor
  MONITOR_WORKAREA = $0002;        // use monitor work area
  MONITOR_AREA  =  $0000;        // use monitor entire area

begin
  w := Prc.Right - Prc.Left;
  h := Prc.Bottom - Prc.Top;

  hMon := MonitorFromRect(@Prc, Flags);

  mi.cbSize := SizeOf(mi);
  GetMonitorInfo(hMon, @mi);
  if (flags and MONITOR_WORKAREA) <> 0 then
    Rect := mi.rcWork
  else
    Rect := mi.rcMonitor;
  if (flags and MONITOR_CENTER) <> 0 then
  begin
    Prc.Left := Rect.Left + (Rect.Right - Rect.Left - w) div 2;
    Prc.Top := Rect.Top + (Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top - h) div 2;
    Prc.Right := Prc.Left + w;
    Prc.Bottom := Prc.Top + h;
  end
  else
  begin
    Prc.Left := Max(Rect.left, Min(Rect.Right - w, Rect.Left));
    Prc.Top := Max(Rect.Top, Min(Rect.Bottom - h, Rect.Top));
    Prc.Right := Prc.Left + w;
    Prc.Bottom := Prc.Top + h;
  end;
end;

procedure ClipOrCenterWindowToMonitor(Wnd: HWND; Flags: UINT);
var
  Rect: TRect;
begin
  GetWindowRect(Wnd, Rect);
  ClipOrCenterRectToMonitor(Rect, Flags);
  SetWindowPos(Wnd, 0, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_NOACTIVATE);
end;
```

Comment: This routine shouldn't be used as such. It passes the wrong flags (confusingly named with a similar "MONITOR_" prefix as constants in MultiMon.pas) to MonitorFromRect(), and it doesn't check the return value from GetMonitorInfo() or GetWindowRect(). And neither does the example code on Microsoft's example code "Positioning Objects on a Multiple Display Setup". :)